# How do you get the "ranking" of an integer attribute in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an `Article` model with a `view_count` attribute.

I want to create a `rank` method in the `Article` model that returns the rank of the article. Ie. highest view_count gets rank: 1.

How would I do this? My first instinct was to query for `Article.all` and write some ruby code to do this. Is there a more efficient way of doing this via queries?

Comment: which database you are using ?

Comment: @ParitoshPiplewar sqllite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not particularly efficient, but something like

```
  def rank
   (Article.where('view_count > ?', self.view_count).count) + 1
  end
```

Comment: That works and seems pretty efficient to me (it's all a query except for the +1)! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can order the elements while getting them from the Databse

`Article.order(:view_count)` maybe with a limit `Article.order(:view_count).limit(10)`

If you really need to store a rank you could now do something like:

```
top_ten = Article.order(:view_count).limit(10)
top_ten.each_with_index.do |article,i|
  article.rank = i
  article.save
end
```

But you would have to update this every time any `view_count`changes so it should be better to just
store the `view_count` and display the rank while you generate the list.

Comment: How would I display the rank when I generate the list?

Comment: @errnesto The first value of index is 0, give first value `i = 1`